# How does case class in scala works internally

Tags: scala

I have 1 question regarding case class of scala

```
scala> case class Person(name:String, age:Int)

scala> val person1 = Person("Posa",30)

scala> val person2 = new Person("Posa",30)
```

In what perspective both the objects (person1 and person2) differs ?

What difference does new keyword plays here?

Comment: there is no difference.

Comment: @Dima--In every document I read this as an advantage where in it is mentioned that we can create objects of the Case Class without using “new” keyword.

Comment: Well, it's "an advantage" in the sense that there's three fewer characters to type, yes.

Answer (score 3):

When you create a case class

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
```

compiler automatically creates a companion object which has a factory `apply` method

```
object Person {
  def apply(name: String, age: Int): Person = new Person(name, age)
}
```

which is invoked when `new` is not used, so

```
val person1 = Person("Posa", 30) // function call creation syntax via companion's apply method
```

is equivalent to

```
val person1 = Person.apply("Posa", 30)
```

On the other hand [instance creation expression](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#instance-creation-expressions) is a constructor invocation on `Person` class (not its companion object)

```
val person2 = new Person("Posa", 30) // invokes constructor
```

Note starting Scala 3 even regular classes can be instantiated using [function call creation syntax](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/other-new-features/creator-applications.html)

> Scala case classes generate apply methods, so that values of case
> classes can be created using simple function application, without
> needing to write new. Scala 3 generalizes this scheme to all concrete
> classes.

Answer (score 1):

Part of what the Scala compiler does (except in the case of an `abstract case class`) with a `case class` is that it generates a companion object for the class with an `apply` method with the same arguments as the `case class`'s constructor and the `case class` as a result type.

When you write `val person1 = Person("Posa", 30)`, that is exactly the same as writing

```
val person1 = Person.apply("Posa", 30)
```

The automatically generated `apply` method is effectively:

```
object Person {
  def apply(name: String, age: Int): Person =
    new Person(name, age)
}
```

Thus `Person("Posa", 30)` and `new Person("Posa", 30)` are the same thing.

For an `abstract case class`, the compiler will not generate an `apply` method in the companion object and will not generate a `copy` method in the case class, thus requiring an explicit `new` to construct an instance of a `case class`.  This is not uncommonly used in an implementation pattern to ensure that:

- only instances of a case class which satisfy domain constraints can be constructed
- attempts to construct using `apply` will not throw an exception

For example, if we wanted to enforce that `Person`s must have a non-empty name and a non-negative age, we could

```
sealed abstract case class Person private[Person](name: String, age: Int) {
  def copy(name: String = name, age: Int = age): Option[Person] =
    Person(name, age)
}

object Person {
  def apply(name: String, age: Int): Option[Person] =
    if (name.nonEmpty && age >= 0) Some(unsafeApply(name, age))
    else None

  private[Person] def unsafeApply(name: String, age: Int) =
    new Person(name, age) {}
}
```

In this, we've effectively renamed the compiler-generated `apply` to `unsafeApply` and made it private to the `Person` class and companion object (where we presumably can know that we're not violating a domain constraint, e.g. we could have a method in `Person`

```
def afterNextBirthday: Person = Person.unsafeApply(name, age + 1)
```

(since we're not changing the already validated name, and if we had a valid age (ignoring overflow...), adding 1 will not invalidate the age)).  Our `apply` method now expresses that not all combinations of `name` and `age` are valid.